# How do I programmatically close an open jquery.reveal.js modal box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the Reveal jQuery plugin. 
http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

I need to programmatically close the model box when I am done with it, however that feature is not including directly with the plugin.

According to Dave in the [comments page](http://www.zurb.com/article/557/reveal-jquery-modal-plugin-),

> "The code is in there, just need to hook it up to be called programmatically."

Answer (score 47):

If your modal's id is 'reveal-modal', then just this line will do it:

```
$('#reveal-modal').trigger('reveal:close');
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it a couple of ways.

Trigger a click via jquery on the dismissmodalclass element (defaults to 'close-reveal-modal')

```
 $('.close-reveal-modal').click();
```

OR

Add this to reveal.js

```
$.fn.hideModal = function(options){
  var self        = this,
      modal       = $(self),
      topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top'));
  $('.reveal-modal-bg').css({'display' : 'none'});      
  modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
}
```

and use

```
$('#your_modal_box').hideModal()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I've been using the trigger() method, but I prefer your suggested method. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The modals class is usually 'reveal-modal'. so changing the lookup to be class based rather than id based, makes this work for more cases:

```
$('.reveal-modal').trigger('reveal:close');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that while registering your reveal div/element.

suppose, [reveal-div] you are registering for reveal. And suppose you have one button/div [close-reveal] onclick of which you want to close your reveal.
Then pass [close-reveal] as [dismissModalClass] as shown below.

```
    $('.reveal-div').reveal({           
        dismissModalClass : "close-reveal"
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me: `$('#reveal-modal').trigger('reveal:close');`

I had a zip text field and a buttom which was opening another pop up

Answer (score 2):

$('#your_modal_box').foundation('reveal', 'close');

works for zurb foundation

Comment: This is what worked for me, must have changed in later releases

Comment: Seconded - this is the only method that appears to work in Foundation, other than triggering a click on the close button itself.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a bug in older foundation/reveal library when calling 'reveal:close' event second time after dialog was hidden and shown again - doesn't work. 
After hours of debugging I found the following CSS hack which force-hides the modal:
$("#reveal-modal")[0].style.cssText = "visibility: hidden;"